# Are 4r70w transmissions interchangable?

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, compatibility

I have a 2006 e-150 that needs a transmission. The transmission I took out was a 4r70w. I found a 4r70w out of a 2000 e-250 on ebay. Can I use that transmission as a replacement? The seller only listed 2000 vehicles as being compatible. It looks like the one I pulled out though.

Comment: Did the buyer check for all possibilities or just assume the year of his / her vehicle?

Comment: Seller, sorry. Im not sure if the seller provided a full list.

Comment: I'd assume there were differences and either get the one that was pulled rebuilt or find an exact match Y/M/M etc... You may want to call a trans shop to verify. NAPA shows different part numbers for overhaul kits so I'd say they are not the same.

Comment: Ratios and torque converter characteristics are likely to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it appears that the electronics of the transmission changed from 2000 to 2001.  Source: [F150 online](https://www.f150online.com/forums/transmissions/506965-transmission-type.html)